# Empty frame is not transparent in animated GIF encoder

Tags: php, animated-gif

I am using this class - http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3163-PHP-Generate-GIF-animations-from-a-set-of-GIF-images.html for my project. But for some reason when an empty frame is provided to the class it fills it with white color. I tried to solve it, but the best I could do - I removed the 186th line:

```
$this->GIF .= ( $Locals_ext . $Locals_img . $Locals_tmp );
```

which simply excluded the empty frame.

Could you help me with it, please. 
Thanks in advance.

P.S. the code below creates an empty frame image resource:

```
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor( 128, 128 );
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image,0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagealphablending($image, true);
    $color=imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 255, 255, 255, 0);
    imagefill($image, 0, 0, $color);
    imagecolortransparent($image, $color);
    imagesavealpha($image, false);
```